How to install Gstreamer on Android Automotive?
I am using the imx8qm on Android 12 and I would like to debug the cameras using gstreamer.
Unlike Yocto, gstreamer is not installed on Android so I had to cross compile it using cerbero.
I created an Android.bp providing the cerbero gstreamer pre built libraries and now I can use the tools gst-inspect-1.0 and gst-launch-1.0 from command line.
But when I run gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src... the system does not find the plugin v4l2src
Also when running gst-inspect-1.0 it only found 1 plugin and 2 features. So I think I am missing something
gst-inspect-1.0
How can I install the full gstreamer with its plugins on an Android system?
What changes can be done in the Android.bp?
Thanks
// Android.bp
package {
    default_applicable_licenses: ["external_gstreamer_license"],
}

license {
    name: "external_gstreamer_license",
    license_kinds: [
        "SPDX-license-identifier-GPL",
        "SPDX-license-identifier-GPL-2.0",
        "SPDX-license-identifier-LGPL",
    ],
    license_text: [
        "COPYING",
        "LICENSE",
    ],
}

cc_prebuilt_library_shared {
    name: "libintl",
    vendor: true,

    srcs: ["libintl.so"],
}

.... More cc_prebuilt_library_shared
....

cc_prebuilt_binary {
    name: "gst-inspect-1.0",
    // defaults: ["gstreamer_common_defaults"],
    srcs: [
        "gst-inspect-1.0",
    ],

    shared_libs: ["libglib-2.0", "libgobject-2.0", "libgstreamer-1.0", "libintl"],

    vendor: true,
    strip: {
        none: true,
    },
}

cc_prebuilt_binary {
    name: "gst-launch-1.0",
    // defaults: ["gstreamer_common_defaults"],
    srcs: [
        "gst-launch-1.0",
    ],

    shared_libs: ["libglib-2.0", "libgobject-2.0", "libgstreamer-1.0", "libintl"],

    vendor: true,
    strip: {
        none: true,
    },

